# Image with transparent background on Launchscreen.storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have a PNG with white text and transparent background on my Launchscreen.storybord. imageView backgound is set to transparent and alpha =1. But when I launch, background seems to become white:

Does anyone know how to solve it? I'm probaly missing a property on image inspector.

Comment: Make the imageView background same as the launch screen background?

Comment: That does seem odd. How are you verifying the image actually has a transparent background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was an Xcode bug. I cleaned the project, restarted Xcode and background became transparent.

Comment: Any reason why? I have a logo with transparent background + custom background on the storyboard

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have a logo with a transparent background. But on the launch screen the background renders as white. Restarting Xcode or clearing the cache does not seem to resolve the issue for me. Did you get this fully resolved?

Comment: Yup, just cleaning the project won't do, you actually have to: Clean the project, close Xcode, reset the simulator (or at least erase the app), open Xcode and run again. Thanks